Интеграция telegram бота на aiogram с bitrix crm
Мне нужно реализовать тг бота, который будет связан с bitrix, 
но есть некая проблема, если я подключаю его напрямую через битрикс, 
я фактически теряю над ним контроль, открытые линии работают, с клиентами можно общаться, всё круто.
Но мне нужна такая логика:

человек открывает бота,
бот с ним здоровается и
если человек нажимает на кнопку,

то информация с бота обновляет лида в битриксе, добавляя в уже существующий лид инфу с ником тг и подключается к рассылке.



Плюс если человек начинает общение с данным ботом, то открывается открытая линия с данным лидом. 
Можете подтолкнуть куда копать?

Если вопрос решен напиши пожалуйста как.

пока не решили.
